# Checking for specific DOM element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a slight problem in the code regarding the if condition check for DOM element, the requirement is that I should not allow 'BR' tag to pass

```
function testclick(handler) {

var nodeList = handler.childNodes;
for (var item in nodeList) {
    if (typeof (nodeList[item].tagName) !== 'undefined') {
        if (typeof (nodeList[item].tagName !== 'BR')) {
            alert(nodeList[item].tagName);
         }
      }
    }

 }
```

the working Jsfiddle is here
http://jsfiddle.net/ganesh_vellanki/agana62d/6/

can some one suggest where I went wrong

Thanks for time

Comment: Just FYI, F12 opens the "Console" in most browsers. Using `console.log` can make printing debug information a lot easier because you don't have to click all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
typeof (nodeList[item].tagName) !== 'BR'
```

you are actually checking the type of the result of the expression

```
nodeList[item].tagName !== 'BR'
```

which will be a boolean object and it will considered truthy always. That is why your code doesn't skip BR tags. Instead, you might want to compare the `tagName` with `BR` like this

```
if (nodeList[item].tagName && nodeList[item].tagName.toUpperCase() !== 'BR') {
    alert(nodeList[item].tagName);
}
```

This converts the `tagName` to upper case and then compares it with `BR`. If they both are different, then it allows the alert to be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function testclick(handler) {

    var nodeList = handler.childNodes;
    for (var item in nodeList) {
        var tagName = nodeList[item].tagName !== undefined ? nodeList[item].tagName.toLowerCase() : null;
        if (tagName !== null && tagName !== 'br') {
            alert(tagName);
        }
    }

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/agana62d/8/

Comment: some browsers send back the case the tag is defined, hence i typically normalize to lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `typeof`. [This is the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agana62d/7/).

Code:

```
function testclick(handler) {
    var nodeList = handler.childNodes;
    for (var item in nodeList) {
        var tagName = nodeList[item].tagName;
        if (tagName !== 'BR' && tagName != undefined) {
            console.log(tagName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use `children` (IE>9) instead of `childNodes`, you'll get just the child elements, and can then skip the `tagName != undefined` check.

Comment: @torazaburo  nice information, really helpful, Thank you very much